# TcpListener doesn't connect/establish a connection

Tags: c#, sockets, connection, byte, tcplistener

i'm trying to start a connection without ManualResetEvent, it's just skip the BeginAcceptSocket telling me to press any key to continue, although with ManualResetEvent i succeeded to get a connection but the client sends me irrelevant bytes.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8484);
        tcpListener.Start();
        tcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket(AcceptSocket, tcpListener);
    }
    private static void AcceptSocket(IAsyncResult async)
    {
        new Client(tcpListener.EndAcceptSocket(async));
        tcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket(AcceptSocket, null);
    }
```

For the example consider Client as the Acceptor for incoming bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`BeginAcceptSocket` is asynchronous; it is not running on the same thread as `Main`, and as a result, your program is ending before your connection is received. To remedy this, either convert to the synchronous `Accept` or keep the main thread active to prevent your program from closing. I recommend you read up on what the [implications of asynchronous methods](http://blogs.infosupport.com/c-5-0-async-explained-as-simple-as-possible/) are before using such methods.

I need to see your `ManualResetEvent` code to answer about that but "irrelevant bytes" means nothing to me because I do not know what you are expecting or what you are getting. Also, I think using a `ManualResetEvent` while also using asynchronous methods in the exact same place really defeats the purpose of using asynchronous methods in the first place.

Comment: I see, now it's all clear. I'm currently reading the article you gave me and I realize my mistake. to prevent my thread from closing i can create another thread and run it there or use the accept method which blocks any activity until the socket is being accepted.

Comment: `to prevent my thread from closing i can create another thread` - Why don't you just run the networking code on the main thread with  blocking? You should of course switch to non-blocking async code when you need that functionality (ie making a server application) but if you don't need it you shouldn't be factoring in it right now. Also, creating a new thread doesn't guarantee the prevention of host process being closed because threads can be created as daemons. Finally, async/await or the async pattern is not quite creating a new thread, it's a bit more in-depth than that.

Comment: I don't like ManualResetEvent, the code is unreadable and i wanted to know another ways to use the function (BeginAcceptSocket) without blocking threads.

Comment: You can use `BeginAcceptSocket` without blocking threads just fine, but in the example you gave, your program will always exit because nothing is keeping it open. Creating a new thread will not solve this, because `BeginAcceptSocket` (et al) do not make any guarantees about when they will start or return **and** they do not block.

Comment: You can use `BeginAcceptSocket` if you want, that's, fine you HAVE to have something to prevent the Main method from returning (once the Main method returns, your program terminates). And unfortunately non-blocking sockets by nature will not prevent that from happening. :) I'm only mentioning this because that's whats in your example

Comment: Well now it's crystal clear, i'll think about a way to handle this.